# I can't make work any local mongodb query by hard coding id with node.js and mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this very basic lines to query a local mongodb collection by node.js mongoose to find a document with its id then update it:

```
mongoose.connect(...).try(...).catch(..)
const Author = mongoose.model("Author", new mongoose.Schema(...))

async function updateAuthor(authorId){
  try {
    const author = await Author.findById(authorId);
    author.name = "new name";
    await author.save()
  } catch (err) { console.log(err)}
}

getAuthor("[an existing author id in my local mongodb]")
```

**This works perfectly when I connect to my distant Atlas mongodb and query out there.
When I try the same code on my local mongodb, I can also make it work if I give to getAuthor() an id through an url call via postman with a json: getAuthor(req.body.id)**.

But when I try to hard code an id copied from my local mongodb (like getAuthor("555fff5555ffff55555")), then I can't make it work, I got the error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'author' of null" because author is null since nothing has been returned by the findById().

I tried a few different things google told me to do but none of these worked:

```
findById(new mongoose.Types.ObjectId("555fff5555ffff55555"))
find({ _id: "555fff5555ffff55555"})
find({ "_id": "555fff5555ffff55555"})
```

Any other query by antoher attribute (by name for example) works fine.

I follow a Mosh course where he uses also findById() and he hards code an id as a simple String without any issue. I tried to uninstall mongoose and install the same version as his, but I still got the same issue. None of the findByID, findByIdAndUpdate or findByIdAndDelete work. Does anyone know why  I can't query by Id on my local mongodb?

**My local versions are:**

mongod -version: v4.4.1  // MongoDB

npm list mongoose: `-- mongoose@5.10.9

Answer (score 0):

The only possible issue there could be that there is no such a document by that id you are querying.

Comment: I confirm 100% there is the id I am querying in the DB, I used a copy paste directly from three different mongodb sources to access the local DB, it's the same result each time: I tried copy/paste from MongoDB Compass, from mongodb console and from a successfull result from postman returning the saved document as json. I tried this with also different documents in the collection.